# How to know perforce retry actually works?

Tags: perforce

According to the [perforce document](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v15.1/cmdref/global.options.html), `-r` specifies the number of times to retry a command (notably, p4 sync) if the network times out.

I disconnected my VPN and tried this command in my terminal.

```
p4 -r 3 -vnet.maxwait=2 sync
```

It threw out connection error for sure, but how do I inspect the details under the hood?

```
Perforce client error:
        Connect to server failed; check $P4PORT.
        TCP connect to myserver:1666 failed.
        No such host is known.
```

Comment: What "details" do you want other than "no such host is known"?

Comment: Maybe like the retry log, cuz it only threw out the error once. I don't know if it did retry and base on what reason it retried or not.

Comment: Based on the output and a quick review of the doc, I don't think it did a retry, because the failure you provoked was instant; the doc says that the retry happens if the network times out, not if it fails completely.